# Getting this error in MongoDB, Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT, Unit entered failed state, Failed with result 'signal'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2020-11-05 10:10:10 CAT; 1min 56s ago

Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

```
Process: 9191 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
Main PID: 9191 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.

Nov 05 10:10:10 ZDR- systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, 
code=killed, status=6/ABRT

Nov 05 10:10:10 ZDR- systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.

Nov 05 10:10:10 ZDR- systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Comment: what "sudo service mongod status" say? and what is "mongo --version"?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.1",
    "gitVersion": "agfg91a9gda31e1gdf5f5cbgfd6956hgfde788bbc54ce1",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu1604",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}

Comment: [rogerdpack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32453) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69199261) saying "For followers, for me (with java and jna) this meant the process had a c-level segfault and had died. [http://betterlogic.com/roger/2019/07/active-failed-result-signal-codekilled-signalabrt-main-pid-5088-codekilled-signalabrt/](http://betterlogic.com/roger/2019/07/active-failed-result-signal-codekilled-signalabrt-main-pid-5088-codekilled-signalabrt/)"